# Can't start jupyter notebook : ValueError

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I tried to install jupyter notebook with

```
pip install jupyter
```

Running `jupyter notebook` returns the following error :

```
  File "/home/usernumber/.local/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 270, in launch_instance
    return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 845, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 88, in inner
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/usernumber/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 2141, in initialize
    self._init_asyncio_patch()
  File "/home/usernumber/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 2117, in _init_asyncio_patch
    nest_asyncio.apply()
  File "/home/usernumber/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nest_asyncio.py", line 14, in apply
    raise ValueError('Can\'t patch loop of type %s' % type(loop))
ValueError: Can't patch loop of type <class 'NoneType'>
```

I am using Linux Mint 20.2 and Python 3.8.

How can I get jupyter notebook to start?

Comment: Have you tried running the command  `jupyter-lab`? See https://jupyter.org/install

Answer (score 2):

`pip install nest_asyncio==1.5.3`
https://github.com/erdewit/nest_asyncio/issues/62

Comment: I believe anything above 1.5.1 will work as well

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).